# Reuse selectors inside reducer with redux toolkit

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux, redux-toolkit

Is there any way to reuse selectors created by `createSelector` inside of reducers?

My use case is that I have a graphql mutation (`createAsyncThunk`) inside of a slice. The function returns only a referenced id, so I will have to filter the passed in state (which is not the root state, but already the slice of it) by the referenced id.

I do have my selectors in place which do have that functionality already, but neither can I use `useAppSelector` nor can I call the selector since it expects the root state.

```
extraReducers: (builder) => {
  // This is from an asyncThunk
  builder.addCase(acknowledgeAllTenantViolations.pending, (state, action) => {
     // Action will pass me a referenced id, I now need to update all violations matching that id

}
```

Those are typical selectors I would like to reuse

```
export const selectViolationsNotAcknowledged = createSelector(
    [selectAllViolations],
    (violations) => violations.filter((violation) => !violation.acknowledged)
)

export const selectViolationsByTenant = createSelector(
    [selectViolationsNotAcknowledged, (state: RootState, tenantId: string) => tenantId],
    (violations, tenantId) => violations.filter((violation) => violation.tenantId=== 
  tenantId)
)
```

If that is not possible is there any way to be handling the `state.entities` better? They are key object pairs and not very accessible since you will need to use `Object.entries(state.entities)`. I found out that I can do something like

```
extraReducers: (builder) => {
  // This is from an asyncThunk
  builder.addCase(acknowledgeAllTenantViolations.pending, (state, action) => {
     
  const {selectAll} = deviceViolationEntityAdapter.getSelectors<typeof state>((state) => state)
}
```

But then I end up at the place where I need to recreate those selectors or at least have them around twice.

Comment: This is a common issue with RTK. The selectors you use in your reducers are "local" where the selectors you use in your components and in your custom actions must be "global". Here are a few approaches to solving this without a lot of duplication..

https://medium.com/trabe/scalable-redux-decoupling-selectors-from-the-state-shape-c46f2f6b1c06
https://randycoulman.com/blog/2016/11/29/globalizing-redux-selectors/